# How to fix leaks memory valgrind using linekd list?

Tags: linked-list, valgrind, ada

I built a set linked list known that I can not add the same item two times to my set so I have implemented this procedure, but when i run program.adb below i still having a leaks memory especially with ***Nouvelle_Cellule := New T_Cellule'(Element, Null);*** then i don't understand this leak memory.

**linked_set.adb**

```
 56     procedure Ajouter (Ensemble : in out T_Ensemble; Element : in T_Element) is
 57         Nouvelle_Cellule, Temp : T_Ensemble;
 58     begin
 59         Nouvelle_Cellule := New T_Cellule'(Element, Null);
 60         if ( Ensemble = Null) then -- Si l'ensemble est vide.
 61                 Ensemble := Nouvelle_Cellule; --Créer une nouvelle cellule.
 62         else -- Sinon, on ajoute à la fin de l'ensemble.
 63                 Temp := Ensemble;
 64 
 65                 while (Temp.all.Suivant /= Null) loop
 66           
 67                         Temp := Temp.all.Suivant;
 68                 end loop;
 69                 Temp.all.Suivant := Nouvelle_Cellule; --Créer une nouvelle cellule.;
 70         end if;
 71     end Ajouter;
```

And I have a simple program using **ajouter** method :

**nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage.adb**

```
  1 with Ensembles_Chainage;
  2 with Alea;
  3 with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
  4 
  5 -- Cette procédure calculera le nombre moyen de tirages qu’il faut
  6 -- faire pour obtenir tous les nombres d’un intervalle entier Min..Max en
  7 -- utilisant le générateur de nombre aléatoire.
  8 procedure Nombre_Moyen_Tirages_Chainage is
  9     Min : Constant integer := 10; -- La borne inférieure.
 10     Max : Constant integer := 20; -- La borne supérieure.
 11     Essais : Constant integer := 100; -- Le nombre d'essais.
 12 
 13     package Mon_Alea is
 14         new Alea (Min, Max);  -- Générateur de nombre dans l'intervalle [1, 10].
 15     use Mon_Alea;
 16 
 17     package Ensembles_Entiers is -- Instantiation du package Ensembles_Chainage.
 18         new Ensembles_Chainage (T_Element => Integer);
 19     use Ensembles_Entiers;
 20 
 21     Ensemble : T_Ensemble; -- Déclarer une variable ensemble.
 22     Moyenne : Integer; -- La variable moyenne qui stockera le nombre moyen de tirages.
 23     n_alea: Integer; -- Le nombre aléatoire généré.
 24 begin
 25     New_Line;
 26     Put_Line("*************************** Début ****************************");
 27     New_Line;
 28     Moyenne := 0; -- Initialiser Moyenne à 0.
 29 
 30     for i in 1..Essais loop
 31         Initialiser (Ensemble); -- Initialiser un ensemble vide.
 32 
 33         loop
 34             Get_Random_Number(n_alea); -- Obtenir un nombre aléatoire.
 35             Moyenne := Moyenne + 1; -- Incrementer Moyenne.
 36 
 37             if not(Est_Present (Ensemble, n_alea)) then
 38                 ajouter (Ensemble, n_alea); -- Ajouter n_alea à l'ensemble.
 39             end if;
 40             exit when Taille (Ensemble) = Max - Min + 1;
 41         end loop;
 42     end loop;
 43 
 44     Moyenne := Moyenne / Essais; -- Calculer la Moyenne.
 45     Put_Line("le nombre moyen de tirages qu’il faut faire pour obtenir tous");
 46     Put_Line("les nombres entre" & Integer'Image(Min) & " et" & Integer'Image(Max) & " est : " & Inte    ger'Image(Moyenne));
 47 
 48    New_Line;
 49    Put_Line("***************************** Fin ****************************");
 50    New_Line;
 51 
 52 end Nombre_Moyen_Tirages_Chainage;
```

Then when I compile and execute with valgrind this program it displays a leak memory related to ajouter function in linked_set.adb:

```
==19122== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19122== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19122== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19122== Command: ./nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage
==19122== 

*************************** Début ****************************

le nombre moyen de tirages qu’il faut faire pour obtenir tous
les nombres entre 10 et 20 est :  34

***************************** Fin ****************************

==19122== 
==19122== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19122==     in use at exit: 17,600 bytes in 1,100 blocks
==19122==   total heap usage: 1,111 allocs, 11 frees, 24,160 bytes allocated
==19122== 
==19122== 17,600 (1,600 direct, 16,000 indirect) bytes in 100 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==19122==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19122==    by 0x4AA78CF: __gnat_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnat-8.so.1)
==19122==    by 0x10C3AB: nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage__ensembles_entiers__ajouter.4561 (ensembles_chainage.adb:59)
==19122==    by 0x10BABD: _ada_nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage (nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage.adb:38)
==19122==    by 0x10B924: main (b~nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage.adb:247)
==19122== 
==19122== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19122==    definitely lost: 1,600 bytes in 100 blocks
==19122==    indirectly lost: 16,000 bytes in 1,000 blocks
==19122==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19122==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19122==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19122== 
==19122== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==19122== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How can I fix this problem please.
You will find the entire code in my github page : https://github.com/MOUDDENEHamza/pim/tree/master/tp/pr2

Comment: Ada is designed with reserved words that are (almost entirely) English words so that the resulting code reads kind of like English. When you choose identifiers that are not also made up of English words, you are fighting against this design choice and making your code harder to read. Also, since this is an English forum, when you post code with non-English identifiers and comments, you are choosing to present the majority of your readers with meaningless identifiers and comments, reducing the quantity and maybe the quality of the responses you receive.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you leak on *deleting*, not *adding* ?

Comment: Thank you, you' re totally reason the leak was on deleting method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the list *before* the inner loop and call `Detruire` (English: Destroy) afterwards. The `Detruire` subprogram uses `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation` to deallocate the list's elements (see [here](https://github.com/MOUDDENEHamza/pim/blob/master/tp/pr2/ensembles_chainage.adb#L7)) which were previously allocated with (in this case):

```
Nouvelle_Cellule := New T_Cellule'(Element, Null);
```

Here's the adaptation:

**program.adb** (partial)

```
for i in 1..Essais loop

    Initialiser (Ensemble);   --  Initialize

    loop
        Get_Random_Number(n_alea); -- Obtenir un nombre aléatoire.
        Moyenne := Moyenne + 1; -- Incrementer Moyenne.

        if not(Est_Present (Ensemble, n_alea)) then
            Ajouter (Ensemble, n_alea); -- Ajouter n_alea à l'ensemble.
        end if;
        exit when Taille (Ensemble) = Max - Min + 1;
    end loop;

    Detruire (Ensemble);      --  Destroy

end loop;
```

**output** (valgrind)

```
$ valgrind ./nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage 
==1353== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1353== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1353== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1353== Command: ./nombre_moyen_tirages_chainage
==1353== 

*************************** Début ****************************

le nombre moyen de tirages qu’il faut faire pour obtenir tous
les nombres entre 10 et 20 est :  34

***************************** Fin ****************************

==1353== 
==1353== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1353==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1353==   total heap usage: 1,111 allocs, 1,111 frees, 24,339 bytes allocated
==1353== 
==1353== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1353== 
==1353== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1353== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There's also a missing deallocation in the `Supprimer` (English: remove) subprogram:

**ensembles_chainage.adb** (partial)

```
procedure Supprimer (Ensemble : in out T_Ensemble; Element : in T_Element) is
begin
   if (Ensemble.all.Element = Element) then
      declare
         Temp : T_Ensemble := Ensemble;
      begin         
         Ensemble := Ensemble.all.Suivant;
         Free (Temp);
      end;         
   else
      Supprimer (Ensemble.all.Suivant, Element);
   end if;
end Supprimer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You add entries to your linked list, but you don’t delete them, so when your program exits the entries are still there in the list, and valgrind sees this as a leak. It isn’t really: the operating system will clean up automatically.

You could just live with this (I would), but if you want to clean up you could do so explicitly as @DeeDee suggests, or you could explore making your linked list [(limited) controlled](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-7-6.html).